# How to append the data to dictionary coming from server response in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am having response from server data but here I need to display as shown in image below in shipping method section which in this carrier title will have sub methods in which it need to display in number of rows in section and for section title carrier title will be named and here method title needs to be appended from a particular carrier title with same names can anyone help me how to implement this ?

The code already I tried is

```
var doubleRemoving : [String:Any] = [:]

do
            {
                let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String : Any]]
                self.responseData = array!
                print(self.responseData)
            }
            catch let error
            {
                print("json error:", error)
            }
            for item in self.responseData {
                let dict = item
                let array = dict["carrier_title"]
                self.keyString.append(array as! String)
                self.doubleRemoving.updateValue(0, forKey: array as! String)
                print(self.doubleRemoving)
            }
            for item in self.responseData{
                if self.doubleRemoving.keys.contains(item["carrier_title"] as! String) {
                    self.doubleRemoving.updateValue(item["method_title"]!, forKey: item["carrier_title"] as! String)
                }
                print(self.doubleRemoving)
            }
            let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            self.keyStatusCode = status
            print(status)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

The Json response from server is

```
[
      {
        "carrier_code": "flatrate",
        "method_code": "flatrate",
        "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
        "method_title": "Fixed",
        "amount": 0,
        "base_amount": 0,
        "available": true,
        "error_message": "",
        "price_excl_tax": 0,
        "price_incl_tax": 0
      },
      {
        "carrier_code": "tablerate",
        "method_code": "bestway",
        "carrier_title": "Best Way",
        "method_title": "Table Rate",
        "amount": 0,
        "base_amount": 0,
        "available": true,
        "error_message": "",
        "price_excl_tax": 0,
        "price_incl_tax": 0
      },
      {
        "carrier_code": "tablerate",
        "method_code": "bestway",
        "carrier_title": "Best Way",
        "method_title": "Worldwide Expedited",
        "amount": 0,
        "base_amount": 0,
        "available": true,
        "error_message": "",
        "price_excl_tax": 0,
        "price_incl_tax": 0
      },
      {
        "carrier_code": "tablerate",
        "method_code": "bestway",
        "carrier_title": "Best Way",
        "method_title": "Worldwide Express Saver",
        "amount": 0,
        "base_amount": 0,
        "available": true,
        "error_message": "",
        "price_excl_tax": 0,
        "price_incl_tax": 0
      }
]
```

Comment: The response coming back from the server is an `Array` of `Dictionaries`. Do you want to transform it into a new `Dictionary` where the `key` is `carrier_title` and the `value` is the dictionary itself?

Comment: Flat rate : fixed Best way : table rate,worldwide Expedited,worldwide Express Saver like this I need to add @Malik

Comment: where is the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var finalDict = [String: [String]]()
let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: getData()!, options: []) as! NSArray
for item in array {
    let dict = item as! NSDictionary
    let carrierTitle = dict["carrier_title"] as! String
    let methodTitle = dict["method_title"] as! String
    if finalDict[carrierTitle] == nil {
        finalDict[carrierTitle] = [String]()
    }
    finalDict[carrierTitle]!.append(methodTitle)
}
```

**Output**

```
["Flat Rate": ["Fixed"], "Best Way": ["Table Rate", "Worldwide Expedited", "Worldwide Express Saver"]]
```

**UPDATE**

To get the count of all the values, do the following

```
var count = 0
for (key, value) in finalDict {
    count += value.count
}
```

Comment: how to get the count for number of names inside it ?

Comment: After `finalDict[carrierTitle]!.append(methodTitle)`, you can get the count by using `finalDict[carrierTitle]!.count`

Comment: no I need to get count for inside values i.e table rate worldwide expedited this count in all keys @Malik

Comment: A count of all the values or count of values per key?

Comment: in this I am having four values count in two keys

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: count of values in all keys I need

Comment: That was my previous question. So you basically want something like Flat Rate: 1, Best Way: 3. Is that correct?

Comment: any idea how to display it in table view like flat rate as section title and inside names as rows in section ?

Comment: That is a different question in nature. You should probably create a new question and I can answer there to avoid over populating this thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029204/how-to-display-data-in-table-view-in-swift-3 here is my question bro just help me