# How to display data in table view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here I need to pass the data to the table view to display and getting lots of errors can anyone help me how to implement this here keys should be displayed as section header title and inside values should be displayed in rows

Here is the declaration for the array

```
var finalDict = [String: [String]]()
```

the output of the array is shown below

```
["Flat Rate": ["Fixed", "Base", "Fixed two"], "Best Way": ["Worldwide Express Saver one", "Table Rate", "Worldwide Expedited", "Worldwide Express Saver"]]
```

Here is the code for table view

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return finalDict.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let names = self.finalDict.keys
        return names[section]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.tintColor = UIColor.white
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let names = self.finalDict.keys
        let a :[Any]  = finalDict[names] as! [Any]
        return a.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingMethodTableViewCell
        let key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
        progressIcon.stopAnimating()
        progressIcon.hidesWhenStopped = true
        var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
        let price = dictionary ["price"]
        let name = dictionary["name"]
        let namePrice = "\(name!)" + "  \(price!)"
        cell.methodLabel.text = namePrice
        cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(paymentRadioAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        if chekIndex == indexPath {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell me the exact error which you are getting?

Comment: First, `finalDict` clearly is *not* an array! Second, "getting lots of errors" what are the error you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, update the following datasource methods

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return finalDict.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let titles = Array(finalDict.keys)
    return titles[section]
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let titles = Array(finalDict.keys)
    let currentTitle = titles[section]
    let values  = finalDict[currentTitle] as! [String]
    return values.count
}
```

Comment: @user0246 self.finalDict.keys is not of type Array but it is a LazyMapCollection thus you are receiving that error. To fix this, change titles from self.finalDict.keys to: Array(finalDict.keys)

Comment: for cell for row at index path how to give ? @Malik

Comment: That would depend on the business logic. You need to understand the concept of how it all works and then go from there to modify it in a way that best suits your needs. Basically what's happening here is you have an `Array` of `String: [String]`. The line `Array(finalDict.keys)` gives you an array of all the keys. Once you have the keys, you can access any key's corresponding array by using `finalDict[someKey]`. After you have accessed the array of strings, you can extract the values by `arrayOfStrings[desiredIndex]`

Comment: Ok thanks that I got it and in the output response carrier title,method title like that amount also I need to get how to implement any idea ? @Malik

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. Could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: `{
        "carrier_code": "tablerate",
        "method_code": "bestway",
        "carrier_title": "Best Way",
        "method_title": "Worldwide Express Saver",
        "amount": 0,
        "base_amount": 0,
        "available": true,
        "error_message": "",
        "price_excl_tax": 0,
        "price_incl_tax": 0
      }` here we had got carrier title and method title like this I need to get amount key value pair data to display @Malik

Comment: like this  as shown in image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/R55oT.png I need to display so I need to get key value pair of amount also to display @Malik

Comment: I recommend making a separate model class (you might have to read up on that a bit). In your model class, create all the attributes that you need. Then. instead of storing the data in finalDict, you just create an array of your model class and assign values to it's attributes

Comment: when I create a model class there is no need of finalDict ? @Malik

Comment: Exactly. Instead of finalDict (which is of type `[String: [String]]`), you will have something like a modelArray of type `[modelObject]`

Comment: I had written model class for getting data but wat u said Instead of finalDict (which is of type [String: [String]]) didn't understand @Malik

Comment: I had written model class and got data and saved it in finalDict then how to get and save amount in it ? @Malik

Comment: Just make another attribute in your model class called `amount`. Save it's value the same way you're storing the values for `carrier_title` and `method_title`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace `self.finalDict.keys` with `Array(self.finalDict.keys)` .